# Regex Match Alphanumeric values with specific conditions

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need to match a string under the following conditions using Regex in C#:

Entire string can only be alphanumeric (including spaces). Example string should only match are: ( numerical values can change)

Example1 String: best 5 products

Example2 String: 5 best products

Example3 String: products 5 best

I am looking to get get "5 best" or "best 5" but the following strings are also matching:

Example1 String: best anything 5 products

Example2 String: 5 anything best products

Example3 String: products 5 anything best

I am using:

```
string utter11 = Console.ReadLine();

string pattern11 = "^(?=.*best)(?=.*[0-9]).*$";

bool match = Regex.IsMatch(utter11, pattern11, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine(match);
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Comment: Try this Regular expression : (best\s\d*)|(\d*\sbest)|(\d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this which I made as close as possible to your regex:

```
^(?=.*(?:best [0-9]|[0-9] best)).*$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/vF5jI8)

If you want to get capture groups, just make a minor change:

```
^(?=.*(best [0-9]|[0-9] best)).*$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/jB1iA5)

It's basically looking for `best [0-9]` or `[0-9] best`, which I understood is what you're looking for.

Comment: From OP: "Entire string can only be alphanumeric (including spaces)". I think you should change the `.` to a character class.

Comment: @Vache I wonder though why OP is using `.*` themself. Plus, the strings that are not supposed to match don't seem to have to do anything about being alphanumeric including spaces, but really about the placement of `best` and the number. Otherwise, I guess we just have to wait for OP to clarify...

Comment: @Jerry : His trying to get best or 5 in the string pattern but your regex capture whole string. If i am wrong let me know ???

Comment: @AnuragJain My regex doesn't capture the whole string. It _matches_ the whole string. The second regex I suggested _captures_ only `best 5` and `5 best`...

Answer (score 0):

Try `(?:(?<=best)\s+([0-9]))|(?:([0-9])\s+(?=best))`

Expects either a prefix of "best" and then whitespace and a number, or a number and whitespace and then a suffix of "best"

Answer (score 0):

How about this (complete example):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> validStrings = new List<string>
        {
            "best 5 products",
            "5 best products",
            "products 5 best",
            "best anything 5 products",
            "5 anything best products",
            "products 5 anything best",
        };

        List<string> invalidStrings = new List<string>
        {
            "best 5 products.",
            "5 best product;s",
            "produc.ts 5 best",
            "best anything 5 product/s",
            "5 anything best produc-ts",
            "products 5 anything be_st",
        };

        string pattern1 = @"^(([A-Za-z0-9\s]+\s+)|\s*)[0-9]\s+([A-Za-z0-9\s]+\s+)?best((\s+[A-Za-z0-9\s]+)|\s*)$";
        string pattern2 = @"^(([A-Za-z0-9\s]+\s+)|\s*)best\s+([A-Za-z0-9\s]+\s+)?[0-9]((\s+[A-Za-z0-9\s]+)|\s*)$";
        string pattern = string.Format("{0}|{1}", pattern1, pattern2);

        foreach (var str in validStrings)
        {
            bool match = Regex.IsMatch(str, pattern);
            Console.WriteLine(match);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var str in invalidStrings)
        {
            bool match = Regex.IsMatch(str, pattern);
            Console.WriteLine(match);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

If you have more examples of what string the pattern should and shouldn't match, I'll refine the expression if necessary.